How to use a conditional with modify-overwrite-beta in JOLT
I'm looking to use the modify-overwrite-beta operation but I'm running into an error. OVERWRITR cannot have TransposePathElement RHS
I've looked into solutions and I found one that almost worked.
Input
{
  "panelTypes": [
    "NUTRITION_FACTS"
  ],
  "jolt_numberPerPack": 25,
  "jolt_factPanel": {
    "nutrition": {
      "serving": {
        "numberPerPack": 12
      }
    }
  }
}

Jolt
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "panelTypes": {
        "*": {
          "NUTRITION_FACTS": {
            "@(3,jolt_factPanel)": {
              "nutrition": {
                "serving": {
                  "numberPerPack": "@(7,jolt_numberPerPack)"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]

I believe the error is coming from my @(3,jolt_factPanel) reference to a field but I need to because I want to validate that the incoming json has a required field before moving on with the operation.
A solution I tried is using the ? operator.
Example Jolt:
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "jolt_factPanel?": {
        "nutrition?": {
          "serving?": {
             "numberPerPack?": "@(4,jolt_numberPerPack)"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]

If there is no panel type, there is a default in place for jolt_factPanel.nutrition to be null. If that is the case the resulting object after running through the jolt above, it looks like whats below. This isn't quite what we want as we want the object to remain null
    "factPanel": {
        "nutrition": {}
    }

Any help would be appreciated!

Hi @peter what is the output you are expecting?

An alternative would be to perform more than one operation to create a variable before the conditional operation. Hope this solution helps.
    [
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "panelTypes": {
        "*": {
          "@": "&2[]",
          "NUTRITION_FACTS": {
            "#true": "hasTag"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-default-beta",
    "spec": {
      "hasTag": false
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "panelTypes|jolt_numberPerPack": "&",
      "hasTag": {
        "true": {
          "@(2,jolt_numberPerPack)": "jolt_factPanel.nutrition.serving.numberPerPack"
        },
        "*": {
          "@(2)": {
            "jolt_factPanel": {
              "nutrition": {
                "serving": {
                  "numberPerPack": "&3.&2.&1.&"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]

